# 取得したHTMLやJavaScriptのコードを Swift のwebViewなどで表示させる方法

Tags: swift, ios, iphone

以下のタグ内のhtmlコードをxmlからparse してきて、webView などで正常に表示させようと考えております。
このhtmlのコードはブラウザで表示させると、twitterのあるtweetが表示されます。

```
<htmlElement><![CDATA[<div class='large-16 columns' style="margin-bottom: 1em;" id="vfwLetter">
            <h3 class="text-center">Read the document</h3>
            <div id="DV-viewer-4501317-VFW-letter-to-to-Trump-regarding-POWs-MIAs-in" class="DC-embed DC-embed-document DV-container"></div>
            <script src="//assets.documentcloud.org/viewer/loader.js"></script>
            <script>
                DV.load("https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/4501317-VFW-letter-to-to-Trump-regarding-POWs-MIAs-in.js", {
                responsive: true,
                  height: 850,
                  sidebar: false,
                  pdf: false,
                  container: "#DV-viewer-4501317-VFW-letter-to-to-Trump-regarding-POWs-MIAs-in"
                });
            </script>
            </div>]]></htmlElement>
```

上記のコードをStringなどで取得し、WebViewで表示させることは可能でしょうか？
もし可能なら、方法などを教えていただけたら幸いです。

また、別案などがあればお教え願えたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLの解析には[XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser)、HTMLの表示には[WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)を使用すると良いでしょう。
以下のコードの `htmlString` の内容を希望のXMLに置き換えれば表示されると思います。
JavaScriptが含まれているドキュメントならJavaScriptの実行もされます。

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Storyboardで接続されているものとする
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    let htmlString = """
    <htmlElement><![CDATA[<html><body>
    <h1>This is a HTML document</h1>
    <p>Hello, World!!</p>
    </body></html>]]></htmlElement>
    """

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let data = htmlString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
        let delegate = ParserDelegate()
        parser.delegate = delegate
        if parser.parse() {
            self.webView.loadHTMLString(delegate.content, baseURL: nil)
        } else if let error = parser.parserError {
            // XMLが不正だった場合
            self.webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><h1>\(error.localizedDescription) </h1></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
        }
    }
}

class ParserDelegate : NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private var inHtmlElement = false
    var content = ""

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        if elementName == "htmlElement" {
            inHtmlElement = true
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if inHtmlElement {
            content.append(string)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if inHtmlElement && elementName == "htmlElement" {
            inHtmlElement = false
        }
    }
}
```

文字列のHTMLをWKWebViewに読み込ませるには、[loadHTMLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415004-loadhtmlstring)メソッドを使用します。
内容によっては、第2引数の `baseURL` を `nil` ではなく、適切な値を与えて上げる必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！loadHTMLStringを使うと良いんですね。上手くjavascriptも読み込めて、WebViewに表示させることができました。ありがとうございました！